# Rails Ancestry Gem Spouse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to create a simple guest list for a hotel, and I want to associate 2 guests who are married. I've looks everywhere, and have not found a straight forward answer.

I just installed the Ancestry gem, but I only see how to associate children and parents - am I missing something? Am I overthinking this scenario?

Any help in the best way to set this up would be greatly appreciated!

My current schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160305173232) do

  create_table "guests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "email"
    t.date     "birthday"
    t.text     "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "ancestry"
  end

  add_index "guests", ["ancestry"], name: "index_guests_on_ancestry"

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ancestry is used to represent a tree structure, a parent-child relation.
A couple is something different. Depending on how much flexibility you need you could just add a `partner_id` attribute to `Guest` and define a `belongs_to` association.

If you need something more complex you could create 
`Marriage` model/table as described by Artyom. Or you could go one step further and create a `Relation` model which can be used to specify how to `Guest`s relate to each other: Relation(from_id, to_id, kind). Where `kind` would be an integer (see Rails enum) or string which specifies the relation (married, parent, child, ...).

Comment: I ended up having a partner_id and used that to associate to a user. MUCH easier than trying to use a gem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As for me? I would create another model (for example Marriage) with params guest_id and guest2_id.
As example:
in Guest model

```
  before_save :set_merriages_reverse

  has_and_belongs_to_many :marriages,
                          :class_name => 'Merriage',
                          :join_table => 'merriages',
                          :foreign_key => 'guest_id',
                          :association_foreign_key => 'guest2_id'

  has_and_belongs_to_many :set_merriages_reverse,
                          :class_name => 'Merriage',
                          :join_table => 'merriages',
                          :foreign_key => 'guest2_id',
                          :association_foreign_key => 'guest_id'
  ...

  private
  def set_merriages_reverse
    self.set_merriages_reverse_ids = self.merriage_ids
  end
```

In Merriage model

```
 belongs_to :guest, :class_name => 'Guest', :foreign_key => 'guest_id'
 belongs_to :guest2, :class_name => 'Guest', :foreign_key => 'guest2_id'
```

Something like this.